# kettle transformation escape commas input CSV file

Tags: transformation, pentaho, kettle

I get a CSV file, each field in this file are separated by commas, taking into consideration the header of 2 lines of the file.
Sample the beginning of a file:

```
Title of the file
Time,User,Pages,Copies,Printer,Document Name,Client,Paper Size,Language,Height,Width,Duplex,Grayscale,Size
2014-05-16 00:06:24,userb,7,1,DLP-SAI-KY4500-BAC3 LDVI,"Crystal Reports",SVXENAPP1,A4,EMF,,,NOT DUPLEX,NOT GRAYSCALE,824kb,
2014-05-16 00:06:35,userb,1,2,DLP-SAI-KY4500,"Crystal Reports",SVXENAPP1,A4,EMF,,,NOT DUPLEX,NOT GRAYSCALE,727kb,
```

Some fields between quote " have commas Example.:

```
2014-05-16 10:25:32,userb,8,1,2LP-GEN-KY1135,"RDV 2014-06-12_ SOCIETE, ABCDEF, TESTK, AABB Normandie, SOCAA Grands Ri.pdf",PC-DLP-50,A4,PCL6,,,NOT DUPLEX,GRAYSCALE,4689kb,
```

In this example, 
"RDV 2014-06-12_ SOCIETE, ABCDEF, TESTK, AABB Normandie, SOCAA Grands Ri.pdf"
is the Document name and contains commas.

How to escape these commas?

That's my transformation :

[image: transformation]

But Option ' Escape : " ' doesn't works

(In my transormation, "Replace char" just allow to delete quote for the DocumentName field)

Answer (score 0):

Your component is missing the `enclosure` configuration. Your sample works for me if I set the enclosure character to `"`.

Comment: Yes it works but when there are several commas that follow (without information between two commas), instead of putting the field to NULL, it skips the field. Example of line : 2014-05-05 17:03:19,Userp,1,1,DLP-SAV-KY300,"Crystal Report",PC-DLP-85,A4,PCL6,,,NOT DUPLEX,GRAYSCALE,279kb,

Comment: I also tried this line. It works for me. Could you pipe your text input into a text output and include the presumably wrong output into your question?